# Swift- How to Divide number of cell items into Sections?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I have, for example, 100 or more (dynamic) number items in my collection view and that I wanted to divide the collection by 20 per section

Section 1 (1- 20)
Section 2 (21 - 40)
and so on...

I already have my code with a simple Horizontal Scroll of Collection View and is working fine.

```
let reuseIdentifier = "cell" 
    var items = ["1", "2", "3", "4",...  ] //lets assume its dynamic array
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    var participantsList = [subList]()
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count
    }
   
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

        cell.myLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
        
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Participant", message: "\(indexPath.item)", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

The result above is this image over here
[image: current look of app]

But what I wanted to happen is like this

[image: expected output]

Basically the app I'm making is a Stamp Rally. I get to scan QR codes and when scanned the item gets colored. Now I get the list of data from JSON back-end and should display them as items in array

The number of stamps should be more than a hundred and might possibly increase overtime.

So what I needed is to divide the number of array in 20 per section and have them displayed and can be scrolled horizontally

Comment: So you don't really have an issue? You would just like to validate if your approach is OK or if there is a better one? This is maybe not the site to do so but... In my opinion this is the best approach to go with. Some other possibilities would be to manually split data into chunks of 20 and then use page view controller. But if collection view solves your problem I would say it is a better solution.

Comment: Well thanks! Now atleast I know I'm not lost on track. The issue I have now is... How do I do it? Can't seem to work over the code